# While installing Jenkins on Raspberry Pi 4B (sed: -e expression 1st row, 65th character: invalid contrast character)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, apt, raspberry-pi4, ubuntu-22.04

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 version on my Raspberry Pi 4B(RAM 8GB).

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
```

I tried to install Jenkins here and set it up, but if I do installation, the following error is confirmed.

```
$ sudo apt-get install -y jenkins

Reading package list... Completion
Creating dependency tree... Completion
Reading status information... Completion
We will install the next new package:
  jenkins
Zero upgrades, one fresh installation, zero removal, and seven upgrades.
You must receive 0 bytes/92.9 M bytes of archive.
After this operation, 93.6 M bytes of disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package jenkins.
(Reading database...)There are currently 224160 files and directories installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../jenkins_2.375.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking jenkins (2.375.1) ...
Setting jenkins (2.375.1)...
sed: -e expression 1st row, 65th character: invalid contrast character
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/jenkins.service → /lib/systemd/system/jenkins.service.
Job for jenkins.service failed because a timeout was exceeded.
See "systemctl status jenkins.service" and "journalctl -xeu jenkins.service" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript jenkins, action "start" failed.
● ● jenkins.service - Jenkins Continuous Integration Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/jenkins.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: timeout) since Thu 2022-12-15 22:49:44 KST; 24ms ago
    Process: 459913 ExecStart=/usr/bin/jenkins (code=exited, status=143)
   Main PID: 459913 (code=exited, status=143)
     Status: "Jenkins stopped"
        CPU: 3min 20.145s
dpkg: error processing package jenkins (--configure):
 installed jenkins package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
There was an error processing:
 jenkins
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've tried many things, but I haven't found an answer yet.

If anyone has experienced or solved a similar phenomenon, could you tell me how to solve it?

① I deleted the package and reinstalled it, ② deleted the apt or dpkg cache, and tried to reinstall it, but the same error continues to appear.

In addition, ③ the same error occurs when performing the same operation after rebooting, and if force the Jenkins service to start while installed as above, java accounts for 99% of the CPU and waits indefinitely as [shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvRy3.png).

As CPU occupancy continues, Jenkins moves to [Bad Message 431](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yjVJ.png).